# Facing " this is not applicable to your computer" error when installing KB2919442

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-8.1, desktop-computer, software-update

I manually tried installing (KB2919442) on my window 8.1 PC which is a prerequisite for (KB2919355), but I get "This update is not applicable to your computer" error each time I tried to install it. How can I fix this?? Thanks

Comment: Where did you download it from? What format did the file have (file extension)?

Comment: It was bundled into March 2014 servicing stack update for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, so you may already have it. Is KB2919355 refusing to install, citing a dependency on KB2919442?

Comment: From what I understand, that's the other way round, but it could be that the OP is trying to install a 64-bit version of the update on a 32-bit platform, or vice versa. We need more info.

Comment: I downloaded it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42162 and the file has .msu as the extension

Comment: @Didier  My PC is a 64- bit version and I downloaded Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu which should work perfectly fine on it but it isn't.

Comment: Try the suggestions here (http://woshub.com/manually-install-cab-msu-updates-windows/), especially the command line option (admin is better), then, if that fails,  install from a .cab file. You've right-clicked on the MSU file and chosen to execute as admin?

Comment: @spikey_richie from the install instruction for KB2919355, it requires KB2919442 to work which makes me try installing it first....  Shouldn't the error be "this file has already been installed" if I have KB2919442 installed somewhere on my PC?? Thanks

Comment: @Que0 - No; If you system already has a patch that has superceeded the patch you would get the message saying the patch isn’t applicable to your system.  Indeed a patch from 6 years ago has already been superseded

Comment: @Ramhoud - Thanks; Did you say I should ignore kB2919442 and go ahead to installing KB2919355 knowing that it might have been superceded.... And also, how do I know I have the patch that supercedes KB2919442, can I get the patch name- KB what??